# Python- how to verify if a string ends with specific string?

Tags: python, string

I have the following string for example:
'         `24499 ?   00:02:05 sys-yg-ys'`

How can I verify if the string ends with a string which I got from a result of a function (e.g `sys-yg-ys`)?

I tried the following (just to check easy case) on the string above:
    result=''
    if (line.endswith('ys',len(line)-2,len(line)-1)):
            result='true'

but I didn't get true when I chech the value of result.

Comment: For the future, you might want to start searching for some basic tutorials. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm contains all the answers you need.

Comment: Googling your question's exact title (typo included) yields many useful results.

Answer (score 18):

[The str.endswith() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) will do this. 
For example: `yourstring.endswith("sys-yg-ys")`

Answer (score 2):

```
re.match(r"^.+(sys-yg-ys)$", string)
```

Comment: Regex is severe overkill for this.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
line = '  24499 ?   00:02:05 sys-yg-ys'
result = False
print("Before test: " + str(result))
result = line.endswith('ys')
print("After test: " + str(result))
```

output:

```
Before test: False
After test: True
```

why you want to add 'start' and 'end' parameter?

Answer (score -1):

you could use

```
 string.find("substring")
```

That should do it

Comment: This will also match strings that contain the given substring elsewhere in the string, not just at the end.

Comment: yeah but looking at your data you don't have to worry about sys-yg-ys appearing in any part but the end of the string, so it is still safe to use it as long as you know what your data will look like.