# How to get the last 10 elements in a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Making a program to check whether the inputted value has a '@gmail.com' in the end.

```
input="abc@gmail.com"
count=1 for i in input:
    count+=1 
print(input[count-11:count-1])
```

Output:: @gmail.com

Comment: `inpt="abc@gmail.com" ; inpt.endswith('@gmail.com')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python- how to verify if a string ends with specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763350/python-how-to-verify-if-a-string-ends-with-specific-string)